unwanted armature node when exporting to unity

Hi I am fixing rigged character in blender and I have wondering if I can export rig with out armature node from blender.
I have already have some gimmick in unity so I want export as it was before export.
Thank you for reading.

What happens when you go into the FBXExport dialog, down to Armature and change the value in the ArmatureFBX Node Type? Try Root instead of Null Maybe?

Thank you for replying, I tried after got the advice, But still there was.

Hmmm, I'm not sure then. It could be that it's some discrepancy between Unity and Blender. I'm more of an Unreal guy :D.

Thank you very much,In my case,I deleted unwanted armature node in maya, and re-exported to unity. That worked. But as you gave me advice, I will have to know about that export dialog and armature node structures more.

Yeah, I've been using Blender professionally for 5 years now and I still have issues with export FBX and armatures/animations every week :D.
